# How i can put on my wordpress the demo of a theme?

Tags: themes

I want to know how to put a demo of a website on my website so that clients can see examples of website designs.

In this image, is the website of a demosite named: LIBERO WP
[image]

In this other picture is the website who put the demo on his site so that his client can see example:
[image]

How you can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To make able publish various "demos" theme, create inside your theme directory `templates` and `php` file with your markup. Then threw the Pages select template you wish to assign, leaving the page empty.
In case of, there is an [instruction](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a HOST A record and put the site in a separate directory for that site. For example demo.mysite.com and just change your wp_options to point to the demo URL (ie. `https://demo.mysite.com` where mysite is the domain of your demo site).

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. If you still have access to your client site and you get permission from the client, you can write code for their site to add a custom banner when visitors land there with certain GET parameters in the URL. Like a banner than appears at the top of the page when you link to something like clientsite.com/?credits
2. Or if you don’t have access and permission to add code to the client site, but you still have all the client’s code and you have permission to use this work as part of your portfolio, then you could create a custom template for your site where you essentially use the code that you created for one of the client’s pages, and you add a bit of PHP at the top of that template to show your custom branding. This might be the most difficult option, but it’s also the most reliable option for your portfolio, because you have complete control over the code and whether the content changes.
3. Or if that’s not feasible for you, then you might create an iframe on your site, where the source is your client site or a page on your client site. This is probably not going to load beautifully, though, and you might need to write a bunch of CSS and maybe other code to make this work well. There’s also the downside that the content may change or go off-line as the client exchanges to their site, so this might seem easier at first, but it might be the least reliable option over time.
4. Or if interactivity is not important to you, and you just want to get this done easily while still making it look professional, then perhaps you would simply save a high-quality screenshot of the page, optimize the file size of feasible, and then embed that on a page on your site.